# How do I get the types of columns for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get the type of the column. For instance I have two columns for names and ids and they are text and integer respectively. I have 3 of them:

```
name    id
george  5
takashi 2
hans    8
```

Is that possible to get a result like that?

```
name id
text int
text int
text int
```

I have seen this code below and it did not work for me

```
select column_name,data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table_name';
```

Comment: You want the data types so often as the number of rows in the table the columns are in?

Comment: @stickybit Once is enough actually when i rethink of it

Comment: What do you mean with *"it did not work for me"*? Seems like a good way to get information about the columns of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the query you already have,

```
SELECT (SELECT data_type
               FROM information_schema.columns
               WHERE table_schema = 'public'
                     AND table_name = 'table_name'
                     AND column_name = 'name') "name",
       (SELECT data_type
               FROM information_schema.columns
               WHERE table_schema = 'public'
                     AND table_name = 'table_name'
                     AND column_name = 'id') "id";
```

would produce the output you want (but only a single row, which is enough per your comment).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/92cb8b/2)

Comment: Thanks but it returns null and what if there are more than 2 columns

Comment: @iyazici: If it returns nulls for you, you have to adjust the parameters (schema, table, or column). If there are more than two columns, you have to extend it to also querying the type for the other columns. The pattern stays the same for every column.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT pg_typeof(column_name) FROM table_name LIMIT 1;`

output: 'text'